# How to extract string before underscore in java?

Tags: java, android, string, extract

example If key of image is `ff8081815848207b01584832ea1d012c_76516_original`

then you have to access image like `image="ff8081815848207b01584832ea1d012c"`

Comment: I suggest that you read the documentation for the String class.

Comment: `str.substring(0, str.indexOf("_"))` also does the trick

Comment: Use: String.split(...)[0]. See the documentation for split.